# EF Core: How to organize models/tables and use DBQuery when I have 2 different tables relating to the same common one

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a bike shops that sell various types of bikes: pro, kids, youth, leisure and any mixture. So I have a table of shops that refers/relates to a table of possible types. Now these shops also host events with the same types: events for pros, kids etc again any mixture. And so I have another table of events that also need to refer/relate to the same table of types:
[image]

**I need to be able in a single quick query get a list of all bike types for a shop or event.**

So I figured I'd have 3 main tables: Shops, Events, BikeTypes and two intermediate to link shops and events to bike types:

[image]

And I organized my models as:

```
public class BikeShop
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class BikeEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}

public class BikeType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class ShopBikeTypes
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public BikeShop shop { get; set; }
    public BikeType biketype { get; set; }
}

public class EventBikeTypes
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public BikeEvent bikeevent { get; set; }
    public BikeType biketype { get; set; }
}
```

With DataCotext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BikeShop> Shops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BikeEvent> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BikeType> BikeTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ShopBikeTypes> ShopBikeTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventBikeTypes> EventBikeTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Migration creates correct database structure just as my diagram. Great!
Now how do I make a straight forward query:

1. get list of all bike types for a shop
2. get list of all bike types for an event

Is my structure even correct?
Do I need some `List<>` in the main object models `BikeShop` and `BikeEvent`?
EF's `include` and `theninclude` seem to require some list?

This feels like such a typical scenario. What's the right way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: it would be much better if u show us to your tables. maybe u can try ```Include(x=>x.anyCollectionOrSingle).ThenInclude(x=>x.anyCollectionOrSingle).ThenInclude(x=>x.anyCollectionOrSingle);```   .  if there is a so much query like this,u should not use ```AsNoTracking()``` and u should use ```AsSplitQuery()``` .

Comment: @BerkGarip: reformatted the question. Please review is possible. Thank you.

Comment: which approach did u followed while u are creating your database ?

Comment: @BerkGarip: I created those models and then ran migration to generate the db. I understand that EF figures out relationships based on usage of models and them having references to each other. So the diagram with 5 tables is the result. Which seems like it gets the job done - data-structure-wise, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the linq queries that you are asked but when i look at that your class models, i can say they are wrong. U need to define first which relation theyre having. if all of that relation has based on one-to-one, u wont gonna need any `List<>` in your class models. but if u have one-to-many relation,u gonna need them.

**1- get list of all bike types for a shop**

```
return DbContext.Shops
.Include(x>=x.ShopBikeTypes)
.ThenInclude(x=>x.BikeTypes).ToList();
```

**2- get list of all bike types for an event**

```
return DbContext.Events
.Include(x=>x.EventBikeTypes)
.ThenInclude(x=>x.BikeTypes).ToList();
```

**3- Get all data in that relation**

```
return DbContext.BikeTypes
.Include(x>=x.EventBikeTypes)
.ThenInclude(x=>x.Events).AsSplitQuery()
.Include(x=>x.ShopBikeTypes)
.ThenInclude(x>=x.Shops).AsSplitQuery()
.ToList();
```

it can be a tough query, do not try to use `AsNoTracking()` because it can cause Cartesian Explosion.

Comment: Yes. It's 1 shop to many bike types and same for event. So my 'BikeShop' and 'BikeEvent' need lists like 'List<ShopBikeType>' and 'List<EventBikeType>'? And 'ShopBikeType' with 'EventBikeType' will need 'List<BikeType>'? Something like that?

Comment: yeah something like that but i think u are following code-first approach, u better look at FluentAPI configuration to define those relationships.

Answer (score 0):

@BerkGarip: thank you for your help. I ended up with this models structure:

```
public class AShop
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public List<AShopType> aTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<AEventType> aTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class AShopType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public AType aType { get; set; }
}

public class AEventType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public AType aType { get; set; }
}
```

In order to achieve what I needed using answer from @BerkGarip I figured out that the trick there was to have lists in the 'shop' and 'event' models to the intermediate objects which in turn have a single reference to 'type'. This way database layout is the same and it is many-to-many relationship and I can use 'include' and 'thenInclude' exactly as expected:

```
return await _context.AShops.Where(x => x.name == "Z")
             .Include(x => x.aTypes)
             .ThenInclude(y => y.aType)
             .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: yeah u are creating a many to many relationship in a indirect way.  for more information about it, u can look at that  : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx