# EF Core - Specify managing side in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got a many-to-many relationship between entities ProductModel and CategoryModel. EF core automatically created linking table "CategoryModelProductModel". To add records to linking table, I need to add a ProductModel to CategoryModel.Products, but I want it the other way around - I want to add a category to a product to create records in linking table.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Perhaps by defining the relationship in some special way in OnModelCreating?
My classes right not looks like this:

Primary key of productModel is Sku + CompanyId

```cs
public class ProductModel 
{        
    //lots of string/int/bool properties    

    public virtual List<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; } = new(); 
}
```

Primary key of CategoryModel is Id.

```cs
public class CategoryModel 
{        
    //string/int properties    
    
    public virtual List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; } = new(); 
}
```

Joining table: `Key = categoryId, ProductSku + ProductCompanyId FK_Category = CategoryId FK_Product = Sku + CompanyId`

I tried leaving it as it is, but when adding a product to multiple categories, the insert fails saying the ProductModel is already being tracked by EF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a special way for that. you have to define that relationship in indirect way. u can look at those links: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67255530/ef-core-how-to-organize-models-tables-and-use-dbquery-when-i-have-2-different-t/67331752#67331752

Comment: Hi BerkGarip,
Thanks for the answer. It appeared the problem was with a nugetpackage I used to bulkinsert my products. After replacing that method with an ordinary Add/update + SaveChanges, it worked as expected (although much, much slower).